# how to wait for a variable to change its value in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, class-variables

I have the following function in my angular app, which runs with buttons click.

```
  submit() {

    if (this.increment) {
      this.setData();
    } else {
      this.submitAction = true;
      this.blockButtons();
      this.currentComponent.submit();
    }
  }
```

when the function enters through the else I want to end with a redirection, but I need to wait until the "this.submitAction" value is set to false. This is controlled in another function that collects the values of a subscription and when it finishes sets the value of "this.submitAction" to false.

How can I do this?
I thought it was something simple and I called the redirect method directly, at the end of the function, but I don't give time to subscribe and when the redirect ends the data doesn't exist.

thank you in advance

Comment: use an observable

Comment: Easiest solution would be to use an Observable (or even a Promise to await for the response)

Comment: Is the subscription made in `this.blockButtons()` function?

Comment: @MichaelD is call in "this.currentComponent.submit()"

Comment: @MarekW even being both of the function  on the same component?

Comment: You need to subscribe where it's value is required. Something looks fundamentally off with the line `this.currentComponent.submit();`. What is `this.currentComponent`? Is it some other component that you've to the present component? Why is it called `currentComponent`?

Comment: is a form in different steps, and currentcomponent refers to the name of each step. In this case I am in the first step and need to make a redirection in case I complete this first phase of the form but I don't advance to the second step @MichaelD